# What is the price of implementing and hosting couchbase lite / mobile myself

Tags: xamarin.forms, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

I'm just getting started with Xamarin development, and I'm discovery the wonders of using Couchbase Light / Mobile to manage local data and data sync. I watched a very nice video from Xamarin Evolve 2014, in which the folks from Couchbase presented some great use cases for using Couchbase in Xamarin mobile apps.
My question is: given, that there are 3 components involved - the Light/Mobile library, the Gateway, and the Server - for me to start my development, and, later on to deploy in production: are all these components commercial, are there an open source counterparts? If only commercial components exist - what is the pricing?

-Eugene

Comment: http://www.couchbase.com/request-pricing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couchbase and Couchbase Mobile are [Open Source under an Apache 2.0 license](http://www.couchbase.com/open-source), with the development in the open on [github](https://github.com/couchbase).

There are two binary releases, a Community Edition and an Enterprise Edition which each have different terms in their license agreements and as pointed out, the [Enterprise Edition is through subscription](http://www.couchbase.com/editions), which gives the subscriber access to Couchbase, Inc. for help, enhancements and an escalation path when you need to resolve something right away.